# What are all the Visual Studio C# pragma names?

Tags: c#, language-features, annotations, pragma

In C++, there was a #pragma to output to the build log.  Does one exist for Visual Studio 2005 C# ?  And, does anyone know where an actual list of all the #pragma names can be found?

Answer (score 3):

According [to the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x74w198a.aspx), pragmas must be supported by the compiler, and only two are currently supported: checksum and warning.

Answer (score 2):

[This link on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx) lists all the C# preprocessor directives and goes into detail about how they are used.

```
#if
#else 
#elif 
#endif 
#define 
#undef 
#warning 
#error 
#line 
#region 
#endregion 
#pragma 
#pragma warning 
#pragma checksum
```

Only `warning` and `checksum` are supported `#pragma` instructions for the C# compiler.

Comment: redirects to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives - which means the old link might become invalid soon